# Javascript using removing duplicate and summing up

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using javascript.

Here is my array

```
 var a=[
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":2   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME2",
          "QTY":3   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":5   
        }
    ]
```

I want to merge duplicates but sum their contributions. The result would be like the following:

```
   [
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":7   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME2",
          "QTY":3   
        }

    ]
```

Comment: there are not duplicates

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @sarankani did the answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```js
var a=[
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":2   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME2",
          "QTY":3   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":5   
        }
    ];
let map = {};
a = a.filter(function(element, idx){
    if(map[element['P_NAME']] !== undefined){
        a[map[element['P_NAME']]].QTY += element.QTY;
        return 0;
    }
    map[element['P_NAME']] = idx;
    return 1;
})
console.log(a);
```

I have used [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and I am using an object as an map to refer to the first occurrence of any element, if it has occurred before, I add QTY to that idx and filter this element out

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and its *this argument* as a `hashmap` to group the results - see demo below:

```js
var a=[{"P_NAME":"TESTNAME","QTY":2},{"P_NAME":"TESTNAME2","QTY":3},{"P_NAME":"TESTNAME","QTY":5}];
var result=[];

a.forEach(function(e){
    if(this[e["P_NAME"]]) {
      this[e["P_NAME"]]["QTY"] += e["QTY"];
    } else {
      this[e["P_NAME"]] = e;
      result.push(this[e["P_NAME"]]);
    }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your JSON is not valid, correct it as follows,

> [
>           {
>             "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
>             "QTY":2
>           },
>           {
>             "P_NAME":"TESTNAME2",
>             "QTY":3
>           },
>           {
>             "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
>             "QTY":5
>           }
>       ];

and then, you can do it as,

```js
 var a=[
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":2   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME2",
          "QTY":3   
        },
        {
          "P_NAME":"TESTNAME",
          "QTY":5   
        }
    ];
var temp = {};
var obj = null;
for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
   obj=a[i];
   if(!temp[obj.P_NAME]) {
       temp[obj.P_NAME] = obj;
   } else {
       temp[obj.P_NAME].QTY += obj.QTY;
   }
}
var result = [];
for (var prop in temp)
    result.push(temp[prop]);
    
console.log(result);
```